# Syncing app limits for Screentime between iOS and macOS

Tags: macos, ios, screen-time

I have an iPhone that I'm signed into with iCloud that has certain App Limits set. I also have Screentime and app limits set on my MBP. There is text indicating that these should be syncing in the macOS preference pane:

> App limits apply to all devices that are using iCloud for screen time

But I'm not seeing those limits sync between my two devices. Is there a way to force that sync?

macOS:
[image]

iOS:
[image]

Comment: You are signed into the MBP with the same Apple ID as the iPhone?  Also, are you using a 3rd-party app for these limits?

Comment: yep, signed into both. Nope, not a third party.

Comment: added pictures for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Maybe it's the same solution for you: Check the Apple ID settings on the iPhone and Mac - If there's a hint "Update Apple ID Info" type in your password and press done. This solved the issue for me.